# Is there a name for this type of warranty?

Tags: software, warranties

Imagine a software company produces a website for a client and has the following warranty:

**Month 1:** Any major or minor code bugs will be fixed free of charge, including any text or graphical errors

**Month 2:** Only major and minor code bugs will be fixed free of charge

**Month 3:** Only major code bugs will be fixed free of charge

The key is that each month the warranty covers less things. Low importance things get dropped as time progresses.

**Is this a normal thing to do and is there an official word for it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. The closest you get is a more general term, "limited warranty".

These kinds of warranties are common in motor vehicles, but pretty much unheard of in the case of software, because the capacity diagnosis of the cause of the problem takes too much expertise which isn't widespread.